# Const-correctness with a linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I am writing a class where multiple instances are linked together like a linked list.  Here's a barebones example of the relevant code:

```
class A
{
  public:
    void setNext(const A& node) { next = &node; }
    const A& getNext() const { return *next; }

  private:
    const A* next;
}
```

I have declared the argument to `setNext` as `const` because `node` is not modified by `setNext`.  Class A does not modify the next node either, so the member variable `next` is declared `const`.  The problem occurs with `getNext`.  Whatever object obtains the next node from the current node may very well need to modify the node, but since the member variable is `const` the returned reference must be `const` as well.

From what I've read, `const_cast` usually indicates a poor design, but it seems like I would have to use it either inside the object that obtains the next node or use it within Class A to return a non-const reference.  Is this a valid use of `const_cast` or is there a flaw in my design somewhere?

And while we're on the subject, is there a preference one way or the other on whether to return a reference or a pointer?  I have `setNext` take a reference to ensure I get a valid instance of A, but the returned value could be returned either way.

Comment: I'd say since A's `getNext` is meant to let others modify the returned object, then A is facilitating the modification of its `next` object, then the `next` member should *not* be `const`. The way I see it, it doesn't matter whether A changes `*next` itself or lets others do it; either way that `*next` does not remain constant, through that particular pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think linked-list private members must be non-const, cause you may want to implement a method which can go across the list an call a specific function on each member, for example. So, your design about a const next member can have a lot of limits. Other thing, you must take care receiving a reference on your setNext : how can you know the end of your list? With a pointer you can set your next as NULL and it'll be the end of the list. But you can keep your member non-const and implement a getNext which return a const object, in this case you'll have :

```
class A
{
  public:
    void setNext(A* node) { next = node; }
    A& getNext() const { return *next; }
    const A& getNext() const { return *next; }

  private:
    A* next;
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, I was thinking very strictly in that A itself does not modify next, but since it is supposed to facilitate the modification of next it should really not be `const`.  In this case the list is actually a circular list, so next should never be NULL.  It is initialized to `this` in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't reinvent the wheel. If at all possible use `boost::intrusive` which has already implemented an intrusive list such as this for you, with no additional work needed! You might even be able to get away with `std::list` or another standard container.

But if you *have* to:

- The pointer to the next variable can't be `const` because you may need to modify the `next` node it points to.
- `setNext` will need to take its parameter by non-const reference, because you need to be able to store a non-const item pointer.
- Create two overloads of `getNext`: `const A& getNext() const { return *next; }` and `A& getNext() { return *next; }`

Comment: This project is for an AVR microcontroller, which does not have the standard C++ library.  This is my first foray into C++, so I'm not familiar with all the available libraries.  Boost::intrusive might work if it doesn't need the C++ standard library, but I don't really need the full functionality of a list anyway.  The list will be a fixed size at compile time and just serves as an easier way to track the objects than an array of pointers.